# parsing value range with units using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to parse the following string:

```
-32000 ... 0 [foo1] some string not intresting
```

the first number is my minimum value and the second number is my maximum value, where the string between the '[]' is my units.

I tried the following code:

```
nums = re.compile(r'.*(?P<minValue>([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)) \.+ (?P<maxValue>([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)).*(\[(?P<units>\w+\])?)')
 minMaxValues = nums.match(inputString)
 print(minMaxValues.group('minValue'), minMaxValues.group('maxValue'), minMaxValues.group('units'))
```

and i got as result

```
 0 0 None
```

Any help in fixing my regular expression is welcommen.

**REMARKS**:

- The numbers can be decimal, negative or positive
- The three points '...' between the min and max are just in the example. It is normally three points but it must be.
- The units can contains strings like 'no units' or '1/min' and not just strings.

Comment: Maybe [`.*?(?P<minValue>[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \.+ (?P<maxValue>[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*\[(?P<units>\w+)?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/kL9fL5/1)?

Comment: Maybe like this [`(?P<Pmin>-?\d+)\D+(?P<Pmax>-?\d+).*?\[(?P<Punits>[^]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/sG1bW5/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex/Python code (already mentionned in the comments):

```
import re
string = "-32000 ... 0 [foo1] some string not intresting"
match = re.match(r'(?P<Pmin>-?\d+)\D+(?P<Pmax>-?\d+).*?\[(?P<Punits>[^]]+)\]', string)
# captures a dash which may or may not be there
# captures digits, minimum 1 time into group 1
# looks for anything that is not a digit (\D+)
# captures digits, minimum 1 time into group 2
# look for square brackets - the unit at the end

print match.group('Pmin')
# output: -32000
```

See an online [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sG1bW5/2).

Comment: i modified your regex string to include decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is always of that general format, why bother with regex?

```
text = '-32000 ... 0 [foo1] some string not intresting'

tokens = text.split(maxsplit=3)

my_min = int(tokens[0])
my_max = int(tokens[2])
index = tokens[3].find(']')
units = tokens[3][1:index]

print('Min: {} Max: {} Units: {!r}'.format(my_min, my_max, units))
```

Comment: *Why bother with regex* - because everything can be done with regular expressions ;-)

Comment: Especially parsing HTML ;)

Comment: This should indeed be the first lesson whatsoever ;)